# Функция для разности timestamp - timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть табличка events, в нее пишутся все события связанные с обьектом, структура следующая:
id, object_id, timestamp, event_type, action

Задача в том, чтобы вычислить дельту между timestamp с event_type= 1
и timestamp c event_type = 2

СУБД - MYSQL

Пробовал с помощью TIMESTAMPDIFF, но данная функция не может принимать более 1 входящего значения подзапроса.
+ насколько я понял, в MYSQL нет в стоке рекурсии.
Подскажите, плиз, мб есть какое-то решение?

Comment: Пример данных, для которых нужно "более 1 входящего значения подзапроса" - в студию. *в MYSQL нет в стоке рекурсии* В восьмой версии есть рекурсивные CTE. А рекурсивные ХП есть давным-давно...

Comment: В смысле пример данных? 
Timestamp, могу конечно для примера скинуть.

2018-09-24 17:41:57

Comment: Пример наполнения таблицы (несколько записей) и результат на именно этих данных, с объяснением, почему именно так, а не иначе. Пример должен содержать все возможные комбинации, способные вызвать трудности. Пример нужно разместить в тексте вопроса  (ссылка "править" под ним) и отформатировать (как код - 4 пробела в начале строки). Также покажите свои попытки решить задачу (то самое "Пробовал с помощью TIMESTAMPDIFF") с объяснением логики построения запроса и указанием, что именно не так.